# Error while trying to add a comment using react and node

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to build a website where users can comment on a given post. i want to display comment when Button is pressed. Everything is working properly but when i click comment then it gives an error:- TypeError: _this3 is undefined.
Quite new in this platform. Please help.

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">

        {this.state.queries.map(function(item, key) {
          return( 
        <div key={key}>

          <hr/>

          <div  className="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary row">
              {item.name}
              <div>
                {item.description}
              </div>
              <hr/>
              <div>
                <button  className="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"onClick={()=>{
                  return(

                    fetch('/queries/'+item._id).
                    then((Response)=>Response.json()).
                    then(data =>{
                      //console.log("comment is:",data.comments);

                      this.setState({comment:data.comments});

                    })
                  )
                }}>
                  Comment
                </button>
                <div id="demo" className="collapse">
                <br/>

                    <form className="commentForm" action={"http://localhost:5000/queries/"+item._id} method="POST">
                      <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="comment..." name="comment"/>

                      <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" >Post</button>
                    </form>
                    <div>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          )
      })}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

json from server at 'localhost:5000/queries/'+item._id

```
{
  "comments": [
    {
      "_id": "5b5eadeeb415381598bdc825",
      "text": "sfsdfsd",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5b5ecbe5b415381598bdc827",
      "text": "hii from alex",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5b5ecd9ed8f72736c830a311",
      "text": "asdad",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ],
  "_id": "5b5ea97f7fb6e02d58b80dba",
  "name": "ram@gmail.com",
  "description": "Is axios still in use?",
  "__v": 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to create a new method for that and then assign it to the onClick method. I think you don't need a return statement for that

```
const addComment = () => {
  fetch('/queries/'+item._id).
  then((Response)=>Response.json()).
  then(data => {
    //console.log("comment is:",data.comments);
    this.setState({comment:data.comments});
})}

... //then use it like this
<button className="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" onClick={this.addComment}
```

Comment: ya, i messed up my code. I'll create a separate method for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are using normal function which is changing your this.
Use arrow function instead to fix this issue.

```
this.state.queries.map(function(item, key) { ... }
```

to

```
this.state.queries.map((item, key) => { ... }
```

Comment: It Worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: one issue, whenever i click comment on one post then all the comment button on every post is also opened.

Comment: how are you opening comment on any post?

Comment: i want  to show/hide comment when i click comment button. I'm using comment button inside map function so all the elements are executing it. how to show/hide comment for individual element?

Comment: you could create child component and render it inside your map, and handle click in that child component so that other comments don't get affected by click.

Comment: yeah i've create child component. Can you help me out with the comment button collapse. i've defined button collapse id just below the comment button. so all the post opens up the comment. where should i put that?